# Coloring a certain part inside a curve drawing

Tags: java, applet, awt, java-2d, graphics2d

I'm drawing a bird.. or more specifically Zapdos from Pokemon.
I want to know what kind of code I can use in coloring inside the beak and outside the beak. Although I'm kind of planning to try coloring the whole part with ovals... but what specific code should I use to color that specific area? It's the only part that I really didn't know.

The beak is made from Graphics2D for curves. (`q.setCurve(x1,y1,controlx,controly,x2,y2)`)
I'm coloring the whole part now with the simple way by setting int x and int y then `g.fillPolygon(coordinates here)`...

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: It's by a teacher. o.o

Comment: Well, please refer them to that article..

Comment: I can't do anything since our semester is about to end and this is like the last project to be passed. C:

Comment: Maybe I will, after the semester ends. xD

Answer (score 0):

The [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) class does not have a setCurve method, so I assume that somewhere your code creates a curved [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) object, and this object is drawn onto the Graphics2D. So instead of the draw(Shape s) method just use the  [fill(Shape s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#fill%28java.awt.Shape%29) method.